# Chrome Extension background script not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

AIM : when ever new tab is opened extension makes a request with the url to server and get the response and change the icon color .

background.js :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
 {
    url = "http://localhost/test.php?"+ $.param({"url":tab.url});
    $.get(url, function(responseText) {
    console.log("sent data");
  });
});
```

manifest.json :

```
 ..."background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] ,"persistent": false },
 "permissions": ["tabs","http://localhost/", "http://*/*"],....
```

this doesnt works .

but when binded with a button on extension page as :

```
function send_url(){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
  url = "http://localhost/test.php?"+ $.param({"url":tab.url});
  $.get(url, function(responseText) {
  console.log("url sent ");
  });
 });
}
```

this sends the url to my local server ! 
is there any thing which is missing with background.js

Comment: You have to load jQuery before you can use jQuery methods... (`$` is jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i was looking for :

```
 "background": { "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js","background.js"] ,"persistent": false },
```