# When reloading my unpacked chrome extension, background.js is not updating to the latest version

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, caching, progressive-web-apps, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm working on a Chrome Extension in React that communicates with Firebase. My workflow: make some changes, run the build script, and then press the reload button on the chrome extensions developer card. Everything I change to the frontend shows right away, but changes to background.js are not being reflected in the files that the extension is serving.

I initially have been trying to add new fields to my firebase collections by adding key/value pairs being sent with the updateDoc() method. I thought there was an issue with firebase until I checked an error through the console by clicking the link to the rendered background.js file and did not see any of my changes. Then I tried putting more console logs in the file, including at the beginning of the file, directly under another console log that is printing, and none of the new logs are printing.

Is there an issue with the backgound.js file being stored in cache, preventing me from updating similar to working with PWA version control?

Thank you

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. Try uninstalling the extension completely, then install it again. Maybe also close devtools for the background script before reloading.

Comment: Do let me know if the below information was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I had the same issue, but I realized that once I need to reload my extension so that it can update its service worker, I had to exit out of the tabs that are running the extension first before doing so.

I didn't have to do this before, but for some reason this is how it worked on myside.

I don't have a source that says that what I just said is correct or not, but this is just out of experience, I would be happy to know if doing this worked for you too.

My guess is that it's because the service worker is inactive when the extension is not being used, therefore that's the only time you can reload it. Again I have no proof other than experience.

Answer (score -1):

The chrome shuts down the background script when it isn't in use and when you need the background script again it loads firebase from scratch and inside this load it checks the tokens and in this time firebase returns null for the current user. added some more logic for fixing this.
You can try to look and set the service worker which clears cache based on versions, and then try if it works,check the this quick [ReadMe for firebase quickstart guide on chromeextension](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-js/auth/chromextension/readme) and [this useful thread on Firebase and Chrome extension](https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/03/power-your-chrome-extension-with)
Also check these following links for similar example implementations:

- [Chrome extension background script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452502/chrome-extension-background-script-not-working)
- [Chrome extension background file reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669568/chrome-extension-background-js-file-reload)
- [How to reload background scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203816/how-to-reload-background-scripts)
- [Chrome extension changes not passing background.js content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961186/chrome-extension-message-passing-not-working-background-js-to-content-js)